# How to prevent laravel scheduler from running before the cron job is finished

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have created a scheduler that runs a cron job. My code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    $user = User::first();

    $schedule->job((new SoapRequest)->checkStatusApplication($user))->everyMinute();
}
```

The task is to make soap calls to a web service to check for application status changes

This is the method `checkStatusApplication` in my `SoapRequest` class that performs soap call to check:

```
<?php

namespace App\ClientRequests;

use App\User;
use SoapClient;
use SoapFault;
use SoapParam;
use SoapVar;

class SoapRequest
{


    protected $password = config('application.password');
    protected $wsdl;
    protected $soapClient;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->soapClient = $this->makeSoapClient();
    }

    private function makeSoapClient()
    {

        return new SoapClient($this->wsdl, [
            'local_cert'   => base_path('storage/') 
            'passphrase'   => $this->password,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'trace'        => 1,

        ]);
    }


    public static function checkStatusApplication(User $user)
    {

        $init = new self;

        $params = $init->makeSoapParams($init->makeXML($user));

        $response = $init->request('SubmitV2', [$params]);

        return $response;
    }

    private function request($functionName, $params)
    {

        try {

            return $this->soapClient->__soapCall($functionName, $params);

        } catch (SoapFault $e) {

            log_system('  fial: ', $this->soapClient->__getLastResponse());
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

**INFO`:** This job it's supposed to run in background.

**MY POINT** is: I want to grab all the users from database that status its not approved for the application and make soap calls in the background to the web service,

**PROBLEM** Let's say I have 200 users that I need to check for status changes.

**QUESTION** *What if from 200 users lets say my third request I get an exception or api server is down, what will happen with my other requests/scheduler or any idea how to handle that, and how to make sure that my scheduler will not run again until all my requests are done example timeout time from api.

**NOTE** I want to run scheduler every minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to prevent your tasks from overlapping by using the `withoutOverlapping` method.

```
$schedule->job((new SoapRequest)->checkStatusApplication($user))->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps

> By default, scheduled tasks will be run even if the previous instance of the task is still running. To prevent this, you may use the withoutOverlapping method:

Comment: I was looking for something like that... thumbs. Any idea how handle exceptions example what if in my second request I get an exception ?

Comment: @trace_le It looks like you already have a try-catch block for handling exceptions, but in your catch block you are calling dd which will cause the application to halt. If you want to continue, then catch the exception without halting.

Comment: I forgot to remove that it was added to check soap exceptions. Thanks !